# How to make Array Covariance work in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, functional-programming, clr

From [Array Covariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/) article:

> Arrays where the element type is a reference type are covariant. [...] It was added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted to be able to support Java-like languages.

Array covariance is supported in CLR, but how can I use this convenient feature in F#?

```
type Foo () = class end
type Bar () = inherit Foo ()

// must have type Foo []
let foo : Foo [] = Array.create 1 (Bar ())
                                // ^^^^^^ must not cast to Foo
// must throw ArrayTypeMismatchException
foo.[0] <- Foo ()
```

In the example, I'd like to have `foo` store a `Bar` array behind the scene, just as implemented in CLR.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In general, F# *deliberately* avoids situations where you have implicit type casting, and array covariance is one of them. So while it might be allowed in C#, it's deliberately **difficult** (though not impossible) in F#, and you kind of need to know the ins and outs of the language in order to use it. Since from the questions you've been asking so far you seem to be relatively new to F#, my first suggestion is to **not** try to use array covariance, but find other solutions (probably involving discriminated unions) to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @rmunn As long as it's not impossible, I'd like to try how to do array covariance in F#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In many places where C# allows implicit casting between types, F# requires explicit casts.

The F# compiler will not even allow a direct cast from `Bar[]` to `Foo[]` (*The type 'Bar []' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.*), you need to cast to `object` first.

```
let foo =  Array.create 1 (Bar ()) :> obj :?> Foo[]
```

By the way, I would not call array covariance a convenient feature, it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: Fully agree with "it causes more problems than it solves". One of the problems it causes is that you can completely *bypass* F#'s type-system safety net, and the compiler won't be able to protect you from certain kinds of **very common** mistakes. The rules of when you use array covariance are kind of like the rules of when to optimize your code. Rule 1: "Don't do it." Rule 2: "Don't do it **yet**". By the time you know when it's appropriate to break those rules, you'll know enough not to get yourself into trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record, perhaps the most notable case where array covariance is useful is when you have a function that takes `Foo[]` and you want to call it with `Bar[]` argument. This is something that is covered by the F# generics, because you can write functions that work for any type that inherits from a given type using the `#Foo[]` syntax:

```
type Foo () = class end
type Bar () = inherit Foo ()

let doFooThings (foos:Foo[]) = ()
let doFooThingsBetteer (foos:#Foo[]) = ()

let bars = [| Bar() |]

doFooThings bars         // error: The type 'Foo' does not match the type 'Bar'
doFooThingsBetteer bars  // no error!
```

Comment: And that's array covariance done correctly. `doFooThingsBetter` can read from `foos`, use functions from `Array` module etc., but it cannot modify the array. If you add `foos.[0] <- Foo()`, the compiler will ignore the type annotation and the function type will be `Foo[] -> unit`. No `ArrayTypeMismatch` exceptions.